# Java Spring Patch RFC-6902 Instant type conversion exception

Tags: java, spring, patch, java-time, rfc6902

I have patching problem which is related to converting the String value the corresponding type. When I try to patch the "Locale" type (or primitives), it works. But it fails for Instant

Entity:

```
@JsonIgnore
@Field("locale")
private Locale locale;

@JsonIgnore
@Field("dateOfBirth")
private Instant dateOfBirth;

@JsonIgnore
public Locale getLocale() {
    return this.locale;
}

@JsonIgnore
public void setLocale(Locale locale) {
    this.locale = locale;
}

@JsonIgnore
public Instant getDateOfBirth() {
    return this.dateOfBirth;
}

@JsonIgnore
public void setDateOfBirth(Instant dateOfBirth) {
    this.dateOfBirth = dateOfBirth;
}
```

Patch method:

```
public static <T> T applyPatchOnObject(Class<T> type, T object, JsonNode jsonNode) {
    try {
        ObjectMapper mapper = new ObjectMapper();
        mapper.registerModule(new JavaTimeModule());
        return new JsonPatchPatchConverter(mapper).convert(jsonNode).apply(object, type);
    } catch (Exception e) {
        throw new UnprocessableEntityException(e.getMessage());
    }
}
```

pom.xml

```
<parent>
    <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
    <version>1.5.10.RELEASE</version>
    <relativePath />
</parent>

<!-- Date -->
<dependency>
    <groupId>com.fasterxml.jackson.datatype</groupId>
    <artifactId>jackson-datatype-jsr310</artifactId>
</dependency>
```

Data:

```
[{"op": "replace", "path": "dateOfBirth", "value": "1971-01-01T01:01:01.001Z"}]
```

The exception:

```
EL1034E: A problem occurred whilst attempting to set the property 'dateOfBirth': Type conversion failure
```

Deeper exception:

```
EL1001E: Type conversion problem, cannot convert from java.lang.String to @com.fasterxml.jackson.annotation.JsonIgnore @org.springframework.data.mongodb.core.mapping.Field java.time.Instant
```

Edit 1:

The following code blocks work:

Code: `System.out.println(mapper.readValue("1517846620.12312312", Instant.class));`
Result: `2018-02-05T16:03:40.123123120Z`

The following code blocks DO NOT work:

Patch: `[{"op": "replace", "path": "dateOfBirth", "value": "1517846620.12312312"}]`

## Solution:

Although the answer from @Babl will probably work, I figure the following things out.

1. As @Babl pointed out, the Spring framework patching is NOT done FasterXML but by Spring Expression Context so all Jackson annotations DO NOT take any effect.
2. I was patching the `User` entity directly which is **VERY BAD** practice.

So I ended up with the following implementation

The Patch library

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>com.flipkart.zjsonpatch</groupId>
    <artifactId>zjsonpatch</artifactId>
    <version>${zjsonpatch.version}</version>
</dependency>
```

The Patch metod

```
public static <T extends EmbeddedResource> T applyPatchOnObject(Class<T> type, T object, JsonNode jsonNode) {
    Assert.notNull(type, "Given type must not be null!");
    Assert.notNull(object, "Given object must not be null!");
    Assert.notNull(jsonNode, "Given jsonNode must not be null!");
    try {
        ObjectMapper mapper = new ObjectMapper().registerModule(new JavaTimeModule());
        return mapper.convertValue(JsonPatch.fromJson(jsonNode).apply(mapper.convertValue(object, JsonNode.class)),
                type);
    } catch (Exception e) {
        throw new UnprocessableEntityException(e.getMessage());
    }
}
```

!NOTE: the`applyPatchOnObject` method ONLY accepts classes which extend `EmbeddedResource`, which in extends `ResourceSupport`. So basically DTOs only.

The entity is the same

Introduce UserDTO with all the proper `Jackson` annotations:

```
@NotNull(message = "locale cannot be null")
@JsonProperty("locale")
private Locale locale;

@NotNull(message = "dateOfBirth cannot be null")
@JsonProperty("dateOfBirth")
private Instant dateOfBirth;

@JsonIgnore
public Locale getLocale() {
    return this.locale;
}

@JsonIgnore
public void setLocale(Locale locale) {
    this.locale = locale;
}

@JsonIgnore
public Instant getDateOfBirth() {
    return this.dateOfBirth;
}

@JsonIgnore
public void setDateOfBirth(Instant dateOfBirth) {
    this.dateOfBirth = dateOfBirth;
}
```

After I have my DTO patched with values. I will use ObjectMapper or some custom way to apply changes from the DTO to the Entity.

All recommendations and advices are welcome.

Comment: Leaving aside the `Instant`-conversion problem, why do you not model the date of birth as `LocalDate`?

Comment: @MenoHochschild I had it with another format. But I want to unify all the "Date" hailing in my applications. That is why all "Date" is now `java.time.Instant`. Not sure it it makes sense, but it reduces the things to worry about.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Basically, the problem is the fact that the data binding is not done by FasterXML but by Spring Expression Context. So adding the `jackson-datatype-jsr310` will not help at all. The FasterXML will be only used if the patch `value` is object or an array. But in your case, the patch `value` is string type so `JsonPatchPatchConverter` will try to convert values using purely Spring tools (Spring Expression Context). So what now you are missing is the String to Instant converter for a Spring Framework. I'm quite sure that there are some implementations available and even maybe some are within the Spring libraries, but I will create here a simple one and show how you can register it.
Initially, let's create a converter (Not the best implementation, just for proof of concept).

```
public static enum StringToInstantConverter implements Converter<String, Instant> {
    INSTANCE;
    @Override
    public Instant convert(String source) {
        try {
            return Instant.parse(source);
        } catch(DateTimeParseException ex) {
        }
        return null;
    }
}
```

And register it before calling the `applyPatchOnObject` method

Something like this will work.

```
// REGISTER THE CONVERTER
ConversionService conversionService = DefaultConversionService.getSharedInstance();
ConverterRegistry converters = (ConverterRegistry) conversionService;
converters.addConverter(StringToInstantConverter.INSTANCE);

ObjectMapper mapper = new ObjectMapper();
ArrayNode patchArray = mapper.createArrayNode();
ObjectNode patch = mapper.createObjectNode();
patch.put("op", "replace");
patch.put("path", "dateOfBirth");
patch.put("value", "1971-01-01T01:01:01.001Z");
// [{"op": "replace", "path": "dateOfBirth", "value": "1971-01-01T01:01:01.001Z"}]
patchArray.add(patch);

// apply the patch
User patchedUser = applyPatchOnObject(User.class, new User(), patchArray);
```

Answer (score 2):

Just to complement the answer above. If you have the `Instant` class available, why use `SimpleDateFormat` then? Just parse the input directly:

```
public Instant convert(String source) {
    try {
        return Instant.parse(source);
    } catch(DateTimeParseException ex) {
    }
    return null;
}
```

A String like `"1971-01-01T01:01:01.001Z"` is already in the format parsed by the method above, so this should work.

If you need to parse inputs in different formats, just use a `DateTimeFormatter`: https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/format/DateTimeFormatter.html